Changing value in one column with sequential information when cell value changes in another column
Cannot find information on web, so asking for help. All solutions I find are on python. I need solution on google sheets.
I have sequential information, which needs to be updated based on values in another column.
sample:
dog 1
dog 1
dog 1
cat 2
cat 2
cat 2
cat 2
cat 2
    3
    3
    4
    4
    4
    5
    5
    6
    7
    7
    7
    7
    7
    7
    8

result I need:
dog 1
dog 1
dog 1
cat 2
cat 2
cat 2
cat 2
cat 2
dog 3
dog 3
cat 4
cat 4
cat 4
dog 5
dog 5
cat 6
dog 7
cat 7
dog 7
dog 7
dog 7
dog 7
cat 8

Vlookup is not a solution, because I have very long list. Please recommend solution without using "ISODD" function. Because there would be cases with text values.

Please don't mix up the Google Sheets tags with Excel tags, read the tag description.

you mean you just need alternating "dog" and "cat"?

@pilchard made my sample more specific.

Ok so it's just a parity check: =if(ISODD(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()+1))), "dog", "cat"). There is bound to be a duplicate

@pilchard I'm sorry dear friend. I made a mistake. I've changed sample once more)

@pichard Can u make your formula more specific? Where should I write "cell references" like A2, B2.

The code I posted just looks at the column to the right of any given cell. If you'd like to use specific cell references then it would be =if(ISODD(B1), "dog", "cat") if the number data is in column B and starting at row 1

Then you'll need to change your condition in the if statement. see the docs: Google Docs: IF function

@pichard There will hundreds of "if" statements then.

Thats how a spreadsheet works

Show what you have tried and what isn't working. Stackoverflow is not a coding service. Also don't keep changing the conditions of the question as it invalidates any discussion thus far.

why? https://i.sstatic.net/GPHkMkoQ.png

There is a dog, instead of cat. Mistake. @player0

use VLOOKUP:
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B:B, {TOCOL(UNIQUE(B:B), 1), ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(TOCOL(
 REDUCE(, SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTUNIQUE(B:B)/COUNTA(A:A))), 
 LAMBDA(x, y, {A:A; x})), 1), COUNTUNIQUE(B:B), 1)}, 2, )))





Here's one approach you may test out:
=let(Σ,unique(tocol(A:A,1)),Λ,counta(Σ),choosecols(scan(,B1:index(B:B,match(,0/(B:B<>""))),lambda(a,c,let(x,c<>iferror(offset(c,-1,)),
 if(and(x,+a+1<=Λ),{+a+1,chooserows(Σ,+a+1),c},if(and(x,+a+1>Λ),{1,chooserows(Σ,1),c},{+a,chooserows(Σ,+a),c}))))),2,3))


Alternative (this ONLY works if lets say 1 or 23 are not going to repeat down the line somewhere again)
=map(B1:index(B:B,match(,0/(B:B<>""))),lambda(Σ,let(Λ,unique(tocol(A:A,1)),hstack(chooserows(Λ,mod(countunique(B1:Σ)-1,rows(Λ))+1),Σ))))



Given the lack of detail from the OP, and repeated changes to the question without any attempt to actually describe the logic at play I think voting to close for detail is appropriate.

Thank you for the alternative answer. It works.
